# Select multiple replace one word with every value in an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, email, str-replace

Okay so I've a contact form I want people to select multiple items, once they submit the contact form I want it to send an email using a html template. I've set it up to string replace the data in the html template, but every time I try to do the array it ether says array or only shows one of the multiple items that were selected.

This is the HTML Select Code I made sure to add [] to make the name into an array.

```
<select class="js-example-multiple js-states form-control" multiple="multiple" name="product[]">
   <option value="Baby Shark Castle 15ft x 18ft">Baby Shark Castle 15ft x 18ft</option>
   <option value="Pirate's assault course 12ft x 25ft">Pirate's assault course 12ft x 25ft</option>
   <option value="Yellow Mega Slide 18ftx18ft">Yellow Mega Slide 18ftx18ft</option>
   <option value="18ft x 18ft Disco Dome Lights &amp; Speaker">18ft x 18ft Disco Dome Lights &amp; Speaker</option>
   <option value="Assault Course 35ft Long 12 ft Wide">Assault Course 35ft Long 12 ft Wide</option>
   <option value="Inflatable Nightclub 12ft x 15ft">Inflatable Nightclub 12ft x 15ft</option>
   <option value="40ft Assault course 15ft x 40ft">40ft Assault course 15ft x 40ft</option>
   <option value="Inflatable Pub 17x17 - Holds 20 People">Inflatable Pub 17x17 - Holds 20 People</option>
</select>
```

This is the php code, I've been successful in replacing the other individual values but when I try to replace one with multiple values it only shows one value. I tried a foreach loop but this only works when I echo the value $product. I want to string all the items selected not just one, I have an example of what I want it to look like below.

```
    // Bring in the email template here
    $html = file_get_contents('template.html');

    // You only need to modify the following three lines of code to customise your form to mail script.
    $email_to = "aaron@pugmanmedia.co.uk";          // Specify the email address you want to send the mail to.
    $email_from = "info@pugmanmedia.co.uk";  //Specify the email address that you want to send the email from. This needs to be Fasthosts hosted,
    $email_subject = "Website Contact Form";    // Set the subject of your email.
    // Specify a page on your website to display a thankyou message when the mail is sent
    $thankyou_url = "../thankyou.html";

    // Get the details the user entered into the form
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $reply_to = $_POST["email"];
    $number = $_POST["number"];
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $products = $_POST["product"];   
    

    // Validate the email address entered by the user
    if(!filter_var($email_from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Invalid email address
        die("The email address entered is invalid.");
    }

    // Replacing the details in the template the above variables
    $html =  str_replace("{{username}}",$name,$html);
    $html =  str_replace("{{email}}",$reply_to,$html);
    $html =  str_replace("{{number}}",$number,$html);
    $html =  str_replace("{{date}}",$date,$html);
    $html =  str_replace("{{message}}",$message,$html);
    foreach($products as $product){
        $list = $product . "<br> test <br>";
        $html =  str_replace("{{list}}",$list,$html);
    };
```

This is the html template code

```
 <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
        {{list}}
    </p>
 </div>
```

This is the result I'm getting

```
 <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
        Pirate's assault course 12ft x 25ft
    </p>
 </div>
```

The end result I want is when people select any number of items for it to all appear in the one place like this instead of above

```
<div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
       Baby Shark Castle 15ft x 18ft
       Assault Course 35ft Long 12 ft Wide
       Pirate's assault course 12ft x 25ft
       and so on
    </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [implode](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b7d5218f8b3ed1e600aed782f509dcb2d8db515)

Replace

```
foreach($products as $product){
    $list = $product . "<br> test <br>";
    $html =  str_replace("{{list}}",$list,$html);
};
```

with

```
$list = implode("<br>",$products);
$html =  str_replace("{{list}}",$list,$html);
```

Comment: Thank you sir you are a hero, Its now working perfectly I tried using implode but had it backwards or something. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
foreach($products as $product){
    $list = $product . "<br> test <br>";
    $html =  str_replace("{{list}}",$list,$html);
};
```

You are actually doing the replace n times, but only the first one will work, because afterwards there is no more "{{list}}" to be replaced. That is not an error, just not what you expect.

Try it like this:

```
$html =  str_replace("{{message}}",$message,$html);
$list = '';
foreach($products as $product){
    $list .= $product . "<br>";
};
$html =  str_replace("{{list}}",$list,$html);
```

Now you are building a temporary String variable with all selected products and then you only replace it once.